# ASP.net C# can't read posted form element

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post, http-post

On my master page I have:

```
<form id="ReportForm" action="HelpAsk.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenReport" type="text" />
</form>
```

This is outside any server tags, just before the  tag.

Jquery submits this form when a button on the page is clicked somewhere:

```
function SendReport() {
    $("#HiddenReport").val("<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>");
    $('#ReportForm').submit();    
}
```

But whatever I try, I can't get my receiving page to read that data:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["HiddenReport"]))
{
    Response.Write("LOL:" + Request.Form["HiddenReport"]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the input element a name attribute to have it posted with the form submit, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenReport" name="HiddenReport" />
```

Also you have two type attributes, remove one of these.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks, it's early in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `name` attribute

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenReport" name="HidenReport" type="text" />
```

name use as key in posted form