# How to send and receive the POST request in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, http-post, dom-events

I have to send the  XML data from aspx using `POST` method and receive the parameters in another Aspx file.

I have stored the XML data in `xmlValidator` named Javascript variable. I tried with the following code but it didn't work for me:

For sending I wrote: `validator.aspx`

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function submit_a() {
        $.post("../All.aspx", { "data": validatorXML }, function (result) {
         alert(result);
        });
 }
</script>
```

And at the receiving point i.e. in `All.aspx`  page I wrote: (read from blog)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
 <%
   NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
     Response.Write(nvc["data"]); //Here i have to call a method written in a .cs file
  // which return some data and print in `validator.aspx`
%>
```

But it prints nothing. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you sniffed it through Firebug, F12 etc?

Comment: where do you expect to write that down ? `Response.Write` - you call this using ajax. And this `alert(Done!);` must be `alert("Done!");`

Comment: I have a problem, I mean i send the post request but how should i know that the data are  received at the other site?

Comment: @Aristos Done , On All.aspx page

Comment: @AmitPal The ajax call is return what you write there on the `result`, then you get the result and you write it down somewhere to your page... eg try `alert(result);`

Comment: @Aristos : Thanks that is exactly what i want, but still it didn't work. Code has updated

Comment: First try this `Response.Write(Request.Form);` to see all posted data. The try to see if the other site page reject the post because aspx have a validation check to avoid hacks.

Comment: NOthing happend @Aristos

Comment: make some trace, debug it.... step on it....

Comment: @Aristos I just have one doubt. Is this the right syntax Response.Write(nvc["data"]); . I read this question and it is giving id instead of data. I mean i don't have so much idea of ASP

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646720/asp-net-c-sharp-cant-read-posted-form-element

Comment: Yes I do not see any other error - as I say you try to use the `Response.Write(Request.Form);`

Answer (score 0):

Read it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx