# how do I respond to a get request on an otherwise empty c# .aspx system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, post, web

I'm trying to build a c# web page that accepts xml code generated by another computer. So I want to accept a string and then send it into my code. 
I have looked here: [Getting a POST variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162495/getting-a-post-variable) but that question lacks the explanation of how to invoke your code opon receiving a request. 
Reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx as suggested in [How to send and receive the POST request in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063023/how-to-send-and-receive-the-post-request-in-asp-net) didn't help either.

I have also found the ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) function that I can override in the aspx.cs. But that does not seem to contain a easy way to extract it's content? 
EDIT seems I can call context.request.QueryString for the data that's inside but how I then respond to said request? Or am I do it all wrong?

something like what I want is:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page{
            BaseSocket bs = new BaseSocket();
    public void OnReceivedPost(object sender , string value)
        {
            sender.answer(bs.ConnectToCode(value));
        } 
 }
```

So that if the other send a web request to www.example.com then it goes into my code (connectToCode).